# Javascript math not working, better way to perform operations?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I included the javascript links above the `<head>`

I'm wondering about doing this in like one line.

I try this in a basic .html file and nothing shows up, no alert.

I'm probably missing something trivial.

Wait, probably just have to put the dollar signs haha

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function compute(){
var h = 1595;
var k = 77;
var r = 309;
var rSquared = Math.pow(r,2);
var x = 686;
var group = x - h;
var groupSquared = Math.pow(group,2);
var toBeSquareRoot = rSquared - groupSquared;
var y_neg = 77 + Math.sqrt(toBeSquareRoot);
var y_pos = 77 - Math.sqrt(toBeSquareRoot);
alert(y_pos);
alert(y_neg);
alert(hey);
}
compute();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `pow()` should be `Math.pow()` - you **must** have your browser developer console open to test things like this, because errors like that are reported immediately.

Comment: Have you even looked at the console?

Comment: I don't know what the console is, and yes I have two screens, code on left side browser in other.

Comment: [You](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) [should](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) [consider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/bg182326%28v=vs.85%29) [learning](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) [what](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.50/en/devtools.html) your browser's console is.

Comment: ha that was cool you linked four browsers in a string, nice. I will thank you, one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few syntax errors. Ditch the single quotes on the alerts. Also, you were missing the `Math.` before the `pow()` method call.

```html
<script>
    function compute(){
      var h = 1595;
      var k = 77;
      var r = 309;
      var rSquared = Math.pow(r,2);
      var x = 686;
      var group = x - h;
      var groupSquared = Math.pow(group,2);
      var toBeSquareRoot = rSquared - groupSquared;
      var y_neg = 77 + Math.sqrt(toBeSquareRoot);
      var y_pos = 77 - Math.sqrt(toBeSquareRoot);
      alert(y_pos);
      alert(y_neg);
      alert('hey');
    }
    compute();
</script>
```

Your code is returning `NaN`. This is probably due to a negative number being passed into the `.sqrt()` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt

Comment: $ symbols aren't required? I see them in javascript or maybe that is jquery. Never mind $ is for jquery

Comment: I updated my current code, no output still. Never mind, missed a Math.pow(), NaN better than nothing haha

Comment: `$` is for jQuery. What do you mean no output? No alert or is it showing `NaN`?

Comment: probably used a radius rather than a diameter, the important thing is it works, so thank you very much for your time.

Comment: No problem. What browser are you using? As the other commenters suggested, using the console solves a lot of these issues.

Comment: Firefox 35 I think on Linux, I also use Chromium, this is the second time console has been mentioned to me, I've been doing php mostly but recently am starting to get into Javascript / jquery for web worker incremented motion maybe not using web workers but something to do with time. It's not an animation, but based on positions like a coordinate system.

Comment: If you're on Firefox -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Chromium -> https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

This will change your javascript coding life forever. You can output values into the console using `console.log()` instead of alerts, and errors are displayed in the console.